# CSS - inner div doesn't stay inside outer div container

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, css-position

I require a responsive background image with an overlay button positioned in the bottom left corner of the image (overlay button is grey now for testing, but will be invisible and used as a clickable link area). This button needs to move with the image as it resizes.

I have tried to do this by having a responsive div 'container' with background image and a button inside the container.

The responsive background image performs perfectly. My grey button is made with CSS % and is responsive. However, the button sticks to the left of the browser window INSTEAD of the left of the container div (where I want it).

I know this is because I have set it to left:0, but I thought it would be left:0 OF the parent container div (the image).

Can anyone suggest how to set up the button positioning so that it is relative to the container div? Or is there another way?

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalDesign/sQ63a/1/

Many thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive positioning example</title>

<style type="text/css">

/* set doc as high as viewport */
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; width:100%; height:100%;}

/* background */
.container {
min-height:100%;
background: #bdecff url(abstract-bg2.jpg) top center no-repeat; background-size: contain; 
    /* imageMap responds to this*/
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;}

/*make imageMap container relative to outer container*/ 
.imageMap           {height:100%; position:relative;}

.imageMap .link     {width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                     position:absolute;
                    left:0;
                    top:0;
                    visibility: visible;}

.imageMap a         {display:block;
                    position:absolute;
                    background:#3b3b3b;
                    z-index:100;
                    opacity:0.2;
                    filter:alpha(opacity=20);
                    border:none;
                    outline:none;}

.imageMap:hover .link {visibility:visible;}

.imageMap .link div:hover a {background:#000;
                    z-index:100;
                    opacity:0.1;
                    filter:alpha(opacity=10);
                    border:none;
                    outline:none;}

/* Left side bottom button */
.imageMap a.weblink     {left:0%; top:78%; width:12%; height:10%;}

/*Right side button*/
.imageMap a.emaillink   {left:87%; top:31%; width:13%; height:6%;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="imageMap">

        <div class="link">
          <!--bottom page button-->
          <div><a href="page2.html" class="weblink" target="_blank"></a></div>
          <div><a href="mailto:#" class="emaillink" target="_blank"></a></div>
        </div>

   </div><!--end imageMap-->       
 </div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/happyjoker/daxe7/1/)

**) change the width & height as you want, and make sure imageMap is get a width what you want to be a relative for others Item ..

Im remove a background image, and I set an normal image like this

```
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="imageMap">
      <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/24qnyix.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;max-width: 300px;max-height: 300px;"/>          
        <div class="link">
          <!--bottom page button-->
          <div><a href="page2.html" class="weblink" target="_blank"></a></div>
          <div><a href="mailto:#" class="emaillink" target="_blank"></a></div>
        </div>

  </div><!--end imageMap-->

</div><!--container-->
```

and css like this

```
/* set doc as high as viewport */
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; width:100%; height:100%;}

/* background */
.container {
            min-height:100%;

            background-size: contain; 
            /* imageMap responds to this*/
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;}

/*make imageMap container relative to outer container*/ 
.imageMap               {height:100%; position:relative;max-width: 300px;width: 100%
height: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
```

}

```
.imageMap .link         {width:100%;
                        height:100%;
                        position:absolute;
                        left:0;
                        top:0;
                        visibility: visible;}

.imageMap a             {display:block;
                        position:absolute;
                        background:#3b3b3b;
                        z-index:100;
                        opacity:0.2;
                        filter:alpha(opacity=20);
                        border:none;
                        outline:none;
                        }

.imageMap:hover .link {visibility:visible;}

.imageMap .link div:hover a {background:#000;
                        z-index:100;
                        opacity:0.1;
                        filter:alpha(opacity=10);
                        border:none;
                        outline:none;}

/* Left bottom button */
.imageMap a.weblink     {left:0%; top:78%; width:12%; height:10%;}

/*Right bottom button*/
.imageMap a.emaillink       {left:87%; top:31%; width:13%; height:6%;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice Anis! I tried your code and you have managed to get the buttons sitting right, however the image has lost is browser resizing responsiveness, instead of resizing it squashes up vertically and horizontally. So unfortunately I cannot use this as a solution, thanks heaps anyway! If you have another suggestion I would love to hear it.

Comment: then if you need as a background image use css3 background size as 100% 100%, its will be resloved a problem, and its fully responsive too

http://jsfiddle.net/happyjoker/jZU2R/

Comment: Hi Anis, I have tried your background 100% 100% idea, however as before it is not behaving responsively within browser. Yes, it fills the page, however it still does not resize as the browser resizes. Instead is squashes up vertically and horizontally - the writing on the page becomes illegible.

Comment: Going back to my original request: Anis do you have any ideas about why the button doesn't stay within the outer container (the image). They are nested within the outer container div and positioning set to relative. Have I set the positioning wrong do you think? Thanks again for your help.